# Enabling multicast communication between 2 AIX JVM processes

Tags: networking, aix, multicast

I'm having trouble with multicast distribution on a single AIX machine between two JVM processes. Think ehcache or jgroups.

In order to enable on Mac OS X:

```
route add -net 224.0.0.0 -interface lo0
```

On Linux (from JGroups doco, untested)

```
route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 224.0.0.0 dev lo
```

What is the equivalent command for AIX?